# Fastest way to get from Suvarnabhumi Airport to down town Bangkok in the early morning

Tags: airport-transfer, bangkok, bkk

My flight lands in Bangkok at 1AM. [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Bangkok#Transportation) states that the train stops running at midnight, it also states taxis will take between 45-60 minutes in rush hour.

Not being familiar with Bangkok rush hour times, how long would a taxi likely take departing between 1am and 2am from the Airport to central city?

Are there any better(quicker, or quicker and cheaper) options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taxis are your best bet. They're affordable, available and, if my memory serves me well, run at a fixed price. Also if my memory serves me well, the taxi fare does not include toll road charges.
Depending on where you're going, you could be at your destination in 20 minutes, but assume 30.

There should also be bus transfers available, but depending on where you have to be in Bangkok, they might not be too convenient, as you might have to take a taxi when in Bangkok anyway.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [Which transportation is best from Bangkok Suvarnabhumi Airport to Hua Hin?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1874/which-transportation-is-best-from-bangkok-suvarnabhumi-airport-to-hua-hin?rq=1)

I have used www.bangkokshuttle.com several times to get from the airport into downtown Bangkok. Clean, quick, and hassle-free.

> Disclaimer: I have ***no*** affiliation with Bangkok Shuttle other than as a satisfied customer.

Answer (score 1):

When arriving in Bangkok we have previously booked with the AOT service when we landed and were waiting for bags to arrive. Very efficient and effective service and when have had deals on booking the return leg.

They offer a variety of cars/services and may be an option you wish to consider if you are visiting Bangkok for the first time and arriving late at night.

Comment: do they have a website?

Comment: Stuart, I don't believe they do although there are a number of counters within luggage reclaim area before you exit for the main terminal arrivals.