# Which travel option is cheapest from Suvarnabhumi (Bangkok Airport) to Huahin at night?

Tags: budget, airport-transfer, bkk

I will reach BKK by 2:00am , whats the cheapest option to go to Huahin by this hour?
Is there any bus available at this hour?

Comment: The situation may have changed in the 15 years since I've been there, but be careful with taxis.  At the time, when dealing with tourists/foreigners, they were notorious for not turning on the meter and then just making up an extremely high fair when you got to your destination and basically bullying you into paying it.

Answer (score 5):

How much is your time worth?

1. The cheapest sensible option is to wait at the airport for 5.5
   hours, then take the [07:30 Airport shuttle bus](http://www.airporthuahinbus.com/suvarnabhumi-airport-hua-hin-bus-schedule-timetable) to Hua Hin for
   **305 baht**.
2. The slightly faster and slightly cheaper, but rather
   challenging option would be to take the little shuttle to the airport's bus terminal (runs 24 hours), then public bus 551 to Victory
   Monument (40 baht, first bus at 5 AM) and then a minibus to Hua Hin
   (200 baht, from 6 AM), total cost **240 baht**.  *Warning*: finding the right minibus will
   be difficult if you don't speak Thai (there's no terminal, they just
   congregate around the traffic circle), and it's not the most savoury
   neighbourhood in Bangkok to hang around before sunrise.
3. The even faster but more expensive option would to take a taxi to
   the Southern Bus Terminal (Sai Tai Mai) for around 500 baht, then
   catch a public BKS bus for around 200 baht, total cost **~700 baht**.  The first bus leaves at
   4 or 5 AM depending on who you believe, and unlike the Victory
   Monument minibus scrum, finding your bus will be easy.
4. The fastest but most expensive option would be to
   take a taxi directly to Hua Hin for **around 3,000 baht** (less your haggling skills are good, more if not).

And for the daytime version of this question, see: [Which transportation is best from Bangkok Suvarnabhumi Airport to Hua Hin?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1874/which-transportation-is-best-from-bangkok-suvarnabhumi-airport-to-hua-hin)